# How to generate this query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

this query used to_char abd group_by

select to_char(date_published, 'yyyymm') yo from blog group by yo;

i have try

```
In [3]: year_field = db.func.extract('year', ArticleModel.date_published)

In [4]: month_field = db.func.extract('month', ArticleModel.date_published)

In [5]: yonth_field = year_field * 100 + month_field

In [6]: print db.session.query(yonth_field.label('yonth'), db.func.count(1)).group_by('yonth')
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM article_meta.date_published) * :param_1 + EXTRACT(month FROM article_meta.date_published) AS yonth, count(:param_2) AS count_1 
FROM article_meta JOIN article ON article_meta.id = article.id GROUP BY yonth
```

is it have a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

```
yonth = db.func.to_char(ArticleModel.date_published, 'yyyymm').label('yonth')
archive_list = (db.session.query(yonth,                                 
    db.func.count(1)).group_by('yonth').all())
```